# Using ado async methods, can I be absolutely sure that rows are returned in order?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ado.net

Maybe a daft question, but I just want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Using the following code; can I be 100% sure that the rows are returned in the order they left my stored procedure?

```
await cn.OpenAsync();
SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the whole async/await thingie, but why read asynchronously if all you do is wait for the task to complete?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis async await is syntactical sugar for the compiler. There's a state machine and a thread put to other use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The difference async makes isn't about query processing, it's about processing the network I/O. async certainly doesn't change the order of network packets, that would be a disaster.

Comment: Well it feels like I've seen some disasters the last year (WinRT). I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: How is the async/await is related (directly) to "processing the network I/O"?

Comment: @agat async is all about I/O. in this case, it's the network I/O.

Comment: @ssg Yep. This is why I actually asked it. How is the await/async even related to I/O? If even to talk about "Async" term in general meaning, that just means "Asyncronous" (i.e., "giving a result with some 'callback' (or something) in some later time, but not at the time you are calling the asynchronous method") -- not sure how you even bound that to I/O (or network).

Comment: @agat we are on a Q&A website, feel free to ask it as a question.

Comment: @ssg You mean, to turn every comment from any thread into any new question on SO? Not sure if this is how SO suppose to work. And not sure why I (do) need to create any new questions. You are the one who suggested an answer, and if you just provided some thoughts, earned (magically) some points and don't want to explain anything else on your answer, then just say so.

Comment: @agat i don't mean that. i just think an effort to educate you individually on what is asynchronous programming is better spent on answering it for everyone who is curious on the subject and who could have the same question in mind. don't you agree?

Comment: @ssg Not sure where you saw any requests from me for asyncronous programming explanations. The only thing I wanted to know is how do **you** possibly see any direct relationship between async/await and networking/IO. I am not sure, I will be so lucky the nearest time to bump into another such unique people. This is why I keep asking it here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, generally **async/await do not add any multithreading "magic"** -- those are just some instructions to make the code easier for reading and writing.

But even if you use some multithreading, **the rows ordering is completely related on the stored procedure you use**.

Comment: I like your "generally". That's the kind of vagueness I'm always using regardless if I know it by heart or not. :)

Comment: How is that a vagueness?

Comment: Well, that not really it (at least, in this very case). This is a sign to notify about the thing what async/await were intented to do (i.e., code reading/writing simplification (without any bringing of multithreading) -- you can find that in details what actually async/away do). However, as long as async method can return a Task<T> to the caller, you are not responsible for where (on which thread) that task was executed. But that's a bit another question -- not related to async/await directly.

Comment: Well if it's just generally, then there might be an exception to the norm right? It's a vague qualifier. Compare it to "always".

Comment: No, "generally" means "speaking of basic way certain function was intended to work". And, "not generally" is also described in the second part of my answer.

Comment: One could argue that if I use multithreading, it's to introduce parallelism and somewhere there we are about to loose the order.

Comment: Well, I don't really have anything to add. You've asked about 'async/await' -- I've described the way it works and pointed, that it does nothing with your (possible) problem. Because, that all only on ADO.NET and ExecuteReaderAsync (which you can call even without async/await (which, again, is just a convenience for you (which just gives a compiler a sign to build some additional wrapper in code, but it does nothing with multithreading itself))).

Comment: So, in that case, your only (additional) question must be "Whether ADO.NET ExecuteReaderAsync method returns rows from db in the same order as it was sent by your stored procedure". But. Why did you decide it's done in multiple threads? Yes, there could be some multithreading, but only in meaning of "your thread -- the first one, and the second one -- with the reader". "Async" just means that  the operation to start the rows obtaining just could take a while -- that does not mean that the query is executed in parallel.

Comment: I've agreed with what you wrote from the start. I just pointed out that generally is a vague word. "1. in most cases; usually." "2. in general terms; without regard to particulars or exceptions."

Comment: Well, I am absolutely not arguing with you. Just explaining it the way I used. But if to return to your first answer, you are right for sure -- it might be used so. he he

Answer (score 0):

The order is set by the database and the query ordering